# How do I add JDK 7 to netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

A few days ago I installed JDK 7 + NetBeans from the Oracle site. When I go to File -> Project Properties -> Libraries, though, the only java platform available is JDK 1.7.

Shouldn't JDK 7 be there? Is JDK 1.7 JDK 7? If not, how to I set it up so I can use JDK 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK 7 = JDK 1.7

1.7 is just the version string.

quotation: "In JDK 7 and JRE 7, the version strings are 1.7 and 1.7.0." (from : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-naming-418744.html)

Answer (score 1):

JDK 1.7 is JDK 7. They're the same.